# how to prevent the system generated "Customer Portal: Customer Portal Reset Password (SAMPLE)" Email Template

Tags: email-template

i  implemented the logic for generating Reset Password Custom Email Template for custom portal user in Apex. once the user reset the password from FrontEnd(PHP Form) using UserName now our code generate the reset password Custom Email Template but this time system also generate the Standard ResetPassword Email Template. **how can we prevent the Standard Email Template generated by System**. pls help

Comment: what method you have used in apex for reset password? If its resetpassword an attribute can be set to achieve this functionality

Comment: Thanks for your response Mohith. i am using System.ResetPasswordResult SR= System.resetPassword(userObj.id, TRUE); this mehthod working properly. apex generated email template successfully but that system also generated standard template that is the problem.

Comment: set the attribute to false...setting it to false will supress standard email i feel

Answer (score 3):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm

System.resetPassword(userObj.id,false)

Setting the second parameter to false will stop the triggering of standard email.

Comment: Thanks Mohith your idea working successfully..... Thanks Kittu